# Merge cells of tables in the header in Word VBA

Tags: vba, merge, ms-word

I would like to merge two cells of the second table in the header of my Word document. I created the script below but it has a run-time error: '5491'.The requested member of the collection does not exist.

The error occured on this line" With xTable(2)"

```
Sub mergercells()
    
    Set xTable = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Tables

 With xTable(2)
 .Cell(Row:=3, Column:=2).Merge _
 MergeTo:=.Cell(Row:=3, Column:=1)
 .Borders.Enable = False
 End With

End Sub
```

Thanks,

Comment: On what line is the error?

Comment: This line has the error " With xTable(2)". I have updated the question. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: There's no second table in that part of the document. Try adding `Debug.Print xTable.Count` and see what the output is (in the Immediate pane of the VB editor)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. it's odd that it shows 0 since there are two tables in the header.

Comment: Does every page have the exact same header?  Also maybe relevant: https://www.office-forums.com/threads/wdheaderfooterfirstpage-wdheaderfooterprimary-or-wdheaderfooterevenpages.1879669/

Comment: The word document only has one page. The reason that I want a script is I don't want to merge cells in every table of multiple documents in a folder.

Comment: If I create a new single-page document and put a table in the header then run `Debug.Print ThisDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Tables.Count` I get `1` so there doesn't seem to be a problem with the code, but something in your document is maybe not what you think...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230560/discussion-between-lucas-liu-and-tim-williams).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is:

```
Sub MergeCells()
With ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Tables(2)
  .Cell(Row:=3, Column:=2).Merge MergeTo:=.Cell(Row:=3, Column:=1)
  .Borders.Enable = False
End With
End Sub
```